# How to infer a form of the function by observing its integral values?

Tags: neural-networks, bayesian, inference, gaussian-process, integral

Let me start with giving an analogy: suppose we have a plant, which grows (gains mass) depending on weather conditions (solar radiation, $x$) and its age/vegetation phase $a$. We can only observe its final mass $m$ and weather conditions $x(t)$, and we have an idea of what the function for momentary growth speed $v(t)$ looks like (e. g. $v(t) = x(t) \cdot a(t)$, or some other form of relation). Basically, it means that the final mass is given by formula
$$
m = \int_{t \in T} v(t)dt = \int_{t \in T} x(t)\cdot a(t)dt 
$$

With this information we want to infer the form of $a(t)$, given that we have many observations of weather conditions and plant masses at different planting sites, and suppose that $a(t)$ should be the same for all plants we observe.

I am almost certain that this inference is possible if we make the problem a little more discrete: if $T = [0, ... ,n]$, than the formula for mass becomes $m = \sum_{t \in T} x(t)\cdot a(t)$, and we can think of the model as of some specific neural network, where $a(t) = a_t$ is a weight of $t$-th neuron with radiation $x_t$ as observed input, and these weights are inferable with backpropagation-like methods.

But as far as I know there is no framework to train a neural network-like model with a varying number of nodes. One thing I have in mind is a Gaussian process, which infers functions describing some temporal processes and also allows specifying prior knowledge and domains for these functions with kernels (e. g. I suppose that $a(t)$ should be continuous and be small at young and old ages with a peak in the middle, so I use a product of RBF-kernel and quadratic kernel), but in my case we, again, cannot use $v(t)$ as our evidence, only $m = \int_t v(t)$, and I have no knowledge of such an algorithm.

Although I have a feeling that there should be enough evidence for $a(t)$ to be determined the same way neural network weights at all nodes are determined given only the "summed" output of the network, I have no knowledge of where to look for an algorithm that would help me infer it the same way backprop-like algorithms would do it for the NN.

Thus, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to construct some modification of Gaussian process, or any other model,  to infer a function with my specific problem setting? If not, then why is my $a(t)$ function is impossible to find given all the (seemingly) comprehensive evidence?
2. How well can this model be generalized to multivariate cases - e. g. when there is not only radiation $x(t)$, but also precipitation $y(t)$ influencing $v(t)$ with possible interactions with one on other? (in other words when the function $v$ takes the general form $v(\vec{X}(t), t)$, where $\vec{X}$ is some multivariate vector)
3. Bonus question - what about specific cases where there is dependence of this speed on mass gained by the plant so far? By choosing the specific kernel for the GP we might avoid necessity to model autocorrelation terms, but in case function $v$ takes the form
   $$
   v(\int_0^t v(i)di, \vec{X}, t)
   $$
   , I am absolutely lost on how to approach such a problem.

Thank you in advance!